# Is there a way to use a command in a bash script that requires a password

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to create a script that adds my SSH private key to ssh-agent.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 ssh-agent /bin/sh 
 ssh-add passphrase_encrypted_key
```

If I run these commands from the command line, I am prompted for the passphrase after the ssh-add command. If I run them as a script, I'm never prompted for a passphrase.

I know this has something to do with subprocessing and/or a sub-shell being created, but I just can't find the information that points me in the right direction.

I have tried commands, "set -m", exec, placing the command in left right parenthesis and maybe a few others that I can't think of right now.

For any response that I receive, a good reference on understanding the fundamentals on how bash scripting works with sub-processes, etc. would really help.

FYI, the ssh-agent is not started by default on the machine that I am using and I am not the admin.

Comment: That script as written won't work: `ssh-agent /bin/sh` starts a new shell, so the following line *never runs* until the shell exits (along with `ssh-agent`).

Comment: Have a look at [expect](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) and [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Comment: When you say you're running them as a script, is it still interactively from your shell prompt, or are you running it in some non interactive fashion?

Comment: @xpusostomos I'm attempting to run it in an interactive fashion, but I'm not successful. I created a sample bash script named test.sh, added the code I've listed in my original question and attempted to run it without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more research, I was able to figure out that I needed to add the following line to my script:

`eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

I don't understand why I need the $, because I thought that was only for referencing variables defined within the shell script, so I have more research to do.

My final basic script looks like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" 
ssh-add passphrase_encrypted_key
```

After the script executes the line which adds the key to the agent, I'm prompted for the passphrase as expected.

Thank you to everyone that has responded.

Comment: note that ${...} <- (curly braces) is the bash syntax to reference variables; in this case,  $(...) <- (parenthesis) is used for command substitution